# Ubuntu not booting: timed out waiting for device

Tags: boot, 16.04

My laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04. While trying to boot it is giving me the following error:

```
97.255199 systemd[1]: timed out waiting for device #device.                                                                                                
[TIME] Timed out waiting for device #device                                 
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for #device                                      
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you edit fstab or change swap, possible reinstall of swap partition so its UUID changed? Check UUID: `sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list` and then check that UUIDs match fstab: `cat /etc/fstab`. If you have to use live installer you have to mount partitions and include that mount in path. But often then easier to use Boot-Repair and check data from its report. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred: my system had Ubuntu 16.04, i tried to reinstall swap using Ubuntu 16.04 cd, but Ubuntu is getting stuck before the installation screen appears. However the installation screen appears if i use 14.04 Ubuntu. Should i go ahead with that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check current UUID of swap partition with blkid? And them compare with fstab in both installs. It seems like 14.04 may be correct UUID and 16.04 not correct.

Comment: Can you post the ouput of   swapon -s

Comment: Hit `s` key to skip detection of failed drives.

Comment: What devices do you have installed?

Comment: Check if you enabled Intel Rapid Storage (RST) / Optane in the BIOS by mistake and disable it...

Comment: 16.04 is EOL now. Try upgrading by reinstalling (but **without formatting**) from a 20.04 ISO, if this still happens, ask again.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1. Remove any additional devices in USB ports.
2. Check available drive space is suitable size. It sounds suspiciously like you don't have appropriately formatted drive space available to the OS.

Oh and

3. Update to the latest OS version.

Comment: It's been five years without an answer for this question, but I can confirm that "Remove any additional devices in USB ports" is what worked on my computer.